# Quantifier question proof

Tags: analysis, logic

The following question I have been doing is below and I'm having trouble with part ii). My working out is below but I think something is wrong. Would anyone be able to help me out with what is wrong with part ii? By the way I'm new here so my mathematical writing may not be typed out the best it can. Thank you!

> Consider the statement
> $$\exists K\in \{1,2,3,4,...\}\quad\forall x < \frac{1}{K}\quad\exists k\geq K,\quad\frac{kx}{1+kx^2}>\frac{1}{2x}$$
>
> i) What is the negation of this statement?
>
> ii) Which is true, the statement or its negation? Prove it."

My answer for part i) is

$$\forall K\in \{1,2,3,4,...\}\quad\exists x < \frac{1}{K}\quad\forall k\geq K,\quad\frac{kx}{1+kx^2}\leq\frac{1}{2x}.$$
My answer for part ii) is

Let $K\in \{1,2,3,4,...\}$ and further let $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} < \frac{1}{K}$. Now suppose that we have that $k\geq K$. Then we get the following:
$$\frac{kx}{1+kx^2}\leq\frac{1}{2x}$$
when $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$.
Thus, the negation of the statement is true.

Comment: Did you know that you can use latex on this site? So you can just write e.g. `$$\frac{kx}{1+kx^2} \le \frac{1}{2x}$$` and it will then look like $$\frac{kx}{1+kx^2} \le \frac{1}{2x}.$$ You can find most commands on google or https://detexify.kirelabs.org/

Comment: please don't use ```calculus``` or ```analysis``` tags. Maybe ```logic``` is a better option. (You can see what each tag is used for by simply hovering your mouse on the tag,  don't know how to do that in mobile)

Comment: @DS Logic would be a nice tag. I only put calculus as this question appeared in a calculus  class

Comment: Your part 2 is quite faulty. In "let $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} < \frac{1}{K}$," is that inequality part of your the $x$-assignment or a consequence of it? (If the former, make use of descriptive phrases like "such that" instead of that confusing two-in-one symbolic sentence). At this point, as $k$ is a fresh variable, it seems to be arbitrary, like how the $K$ at the beginning of the sentence is an arbitrary natural number. And notice that whatever the answer to my question before, $k$ is being pre-restricted such that the next part is no longer referring to every $k$ that is not smaller than $K.$

Comment: @student91 - Better to point to this site's own [MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition that there is something wrong in your answer to part ii is correct. Let's consider two cases:

1. If it is assumed that $x$ must be positive, then the inequality
   $$
   \frac{kx}{1+kx^2} \le \frac{1}{2x} \tag{1}
   $$
   is satisfied iff $k\leq\frac{1}{x^2}$. Therefore, for any $x\in\left(0,\frac{1}{K}\right)$ there exists $k>K^2\geq K$ that violates $(1)$, so the negation of the original statement is false.
2. On the other hand, the negation of the original statement is true if $x$ is allowed to be negative. Indeed, when $x<0$ inequality $(1)$ is satisfied iff $k\geq \frac{1}{x^2}$, hence it is satisfied for all $k\geq K$ if $x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{K}}$.

Answer (score 1):

In part (ii), you tried to prove a statement of the form

$$ \forall K\ \exists x\ \forall k\ P(x,k). $$

Because of the sequence of the quantifiers, you may allow $x$ to depend on $K$,
but you **must not** make $x$ dependent on $k.$
Since your attempted proof only works if $x = 1/\sqrt k,$ it is not valid.

(I have omitted the domains of $K,$ $x,$ and $k$ to simplify the presentation of the statement, because we don't need to consider the domains in order to see that you are not allowed to say $x = 1/\sqrt k.$ For a full proof of such a statement, of course, the domains typically will matter.)